# Having trouble to design the data pattern in swiftui

Tags: ios, swiftui, design-patterns, mvvm, avfoundation

I am creating a camera app
I have a `CameraService` which is an ObservableObject and it runs the session. and update some UI according to session status.Then I inject it using `.envrionmentObject()`

in camera service I have a `SettingHolder`, which is also an ObservableObject, it inits using the `deviceinput` variable from the session. It contains the settings status of the camera, users can change it and on screen.

Basically it works like that:

```
class CameraService:ObservableObject{
   @Published var xxxxxxx
   var settingHolder:SettingHolder?
   func createHolder(){
       settingHolder = SettingHolder(deviceinput)//variable in service
   }
}
class SettingHolder:ObservableObject{
   @Published var focusMode = .lock//view use this to display
   ...
   var input//get from outside
   func changeFocus(){}//using input to change focus
}
```

But to make the @Published var in `SettingHolder` can update the view, I have to pass the object from upper view instead of using @EnvironmentObject, and I have use a weird way to init my view

```
@StateObject var service:CameraService
@StateObject var holder:SettingHolder
    init(service:CameraService){
        self._service = StateObject(wrappedValue: service)
        self._holder = StateObject(wrappedValue: service.settingHolder)
    }
```

I know it is a bad way using singleton and this post also suggest do not nest the ObservableObject [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61666535/swiftui-get-values-of-another-viewmodel-in-a-viewmodel). But I don't know how to find a better way. So confused about this part.

Comment: Why not have _one_ `ObservableObject` that stores both the `focusMode` and `xxxxxx`?

Comment: By the way, the question is likely to get closed as opinion-based, since you've asked the "best way" to architect the app

Comment: @jnpdx because there are too many codes in service already, and their job is different I think.

Comment: I agree; Either add the settings to the `CameraService` or if you want to have a separate object, have `SettingHolder` in the environment too.  it is an object, so `CameraService` can hold a reference to it if needed

Comment: when passing your model using `.envrionmentObject()` as you say, you should use
 `@EnvironmentObject var service: CameraService` etc... not `@StateObject ...`
 and do your weird stuff in `.onAppear{...}`